# Bit extracting in embedded c

Tags: c

I am working on bit extracting from given byte.I have 32-bit  0XFA73DECB in binary 1111 10**10 0111 0011 1101 11**10 1100 1011.Now how to extract bit no. 7 to 22? Any one help me?

Comment: What do you mean by the extraction?  You can shift by 7 and mask upper bits, But I do not know what do you want to do?

Comment: I want to get those bits as it is,remaining turned off.

Answer (score 0):

The following code first extracts the bits into another int and then outputs in binary.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
unsigned int a = 0xfa73decb;
int main()
{
    unsigned int Bits = 0b00000011111111111111110000000000;
    unsigned int Extract = (a & Bits) >> 10;
    char Bin[20];
    _itoa(Extract, Bin, 2);
    printf("%s\n", Bin);
    while (1);
}
```

The _itoa (the underline is because I'm using Visual Studio and the typical itoa is deprecated) means transform the integer Extract into a string with the radix of 2 and store it into the string Bin

Answer (score 0):

To  dynamically reading the inputs to extract the bits,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
unsigned int a = 0xfa73decb;

int main()
{
   int msb;
   int lsb;
   unsigned int Extract;

   printf("size of unsigned int = %d\n", sizeof(unsigned int));     // sizeof int : 4 bytes (32 bits)

   scanf("%d", &lsb);              // as per your requirement: 10
   scanf("%d", &msb);              // as per your requirement: 26

   msb = (8*sizeof(unsigned int)) - msb;         // msb = 32 - 26 ; // 6 
   lsb = lsb + msb ;                             // lsb = 10 + 6 ;  // 16

   Extract = (a << msb);                        // shifting 6 times left
   printf("After Left shift = 0x%0x\n", Extract);
   Extract = Extract >> lsb;                   // shifting 16 times right
   printf("After Right shift = 0x%0x\n", Extract);

}
```

Input:

```
10 26
```

Output:

```
size of unsigned int = 4
After Left shift = 0x9cf7b2c0
After Right shift = 0x9cf7
```